# Is an Ubuntu One account necessary for Ubuntu Core?

Tags: server, ubuntu-core, user-management

I have been installing both Ubuntu Server 22 and Ubuntu Core 22 over the last two months in order to learn more details about it.

One of the main difference I see is that when I install Ubuntu Core it asks me for a Ubuntu One account during install and binds the install to that account and downloads the keys from the Ubuntu One account.

Ubuntu Server is not dependent on a Ubuntu One account and does not ask for it during install or anytime after.

To make it clear about what is meant by "container Linux" before I ask a question about it.  Here are sort stand outs for this category of operating systems:

- Immutability of the operating systems
- Remote updates kernel & apps
- Lightweight & fast (minimal operating system)
- Run many different types of container workloads at scale.
- Ability to reset system to default or factory

Here is the question:

- If I wanted a container Ubuntu Linux without a Ubuntu One account is this possible?
- Also, can I create user accounts on Ubuntu Core after installing it and SSH to it using a user name and password.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Core is intended for 100% unmanaged operation. It's the base upon which you install snaps to form a robust, secure, self-updating appliance that doesn't require a human to maintain it.

While you can try using Core like a standard server, be prepared for a bit of culture shock and a learning curve. It's not a complete, full-featured Ubuntu Server out-of-the-box. It's the minimal base upon which you add your various service snaps.

Ubuntu Core is an excellent host for a container hypervisor. It works best if the hypervisor comes as a Snap package. LXD containers on Core, for example, feel and act like server VMs. I have hosted many different kinds of servers in those containers.

As part of "secure" Ubuntu Core needs an SSH key for the first boot so you can login. That's why your key needs to be at Ubuntu One -- so the Core system, upon first boot, can download it. After your successful first login, Ubuntu Core does NOT dial home for key ever again. You can promptly delete your SSO information, change your keys on the device, or change your ssh settings to passwords instead; whatever you like. Best practice is to retain key-based access for the admin only, and build other accounts (and their access) in a classic Ubuntu Server (or similar) container.

Comment: this is all very good stuff.  I am selecting OSs for a IoT project and it got me thinking about Ubuntu One account and if this is necessary or if I can create devices that can be managed by multiple Ubuntu One accounts or a master account with sub accounts or just use a 3rd party management platform that would allow it.  Being able to ditch the Ubuntu One account for something with more flexibility that would have field service accounts and tiers is an important consideration.